# Brightness goes to max while watching youtube after setting it to a lower values using xrandr in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, display, lenovo, brightness, xrandr

I changed my brightness to a particular value using `xrandr`. But when when I start playing a youtube video, it goes to max automatically. This only happens the first time.
The command I used is

```
xrandr --output eDP --brightness 0.6
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS and a lenovo system.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @yaska Not yet,